# How to get Visual Studio 2012 to grey out ifdef instead of dimming it

Tags: visual-studio-2012, syntax-highlighting

In our code there are lots of passages that are ifdef'ed out. With the former version of Visual Studio, they had been greyed out. With Visual Studio 2012, however, they are no longer greyed out but dimmed, i.e. these passages appear with all the colours of the syntax highlighting scheme, but with less saturated colours. The programmer at Microsoft who implemented this must have thought this very cool, but in practise it makes it really hard to tell if a passage is active or inactive.

Has anyone found a way to tricking Visual Studio 2012 to using the old way of greying out inactive passages?

Thanks for any reply

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have an `Opacity` setting you can change:

In `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Formatting`
you can change the *`Inactive Code Opacity Percent`*. Default is 65, change it to something higher.
Or
Just set the *`Disable Inactive Code Opacity`* to `True` if you want to cancel this altogether.

[image]