# Turn off Visual Studio 2013 PreProcessor Graying Out C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, syntax-highlighting

When I put code inside an #if STATEMENT block in C#, Visual Studio grays out the entire block, ruining syntax highlighting, Find All References... and all those great Visual Studio features.

Is there a way I can disable this graying out of code or are pre-processor statements to confusing for Visual Studio?

I looked at some other posts: [How to get Visual Studio 2012 to grey out ifdef instead of dimming it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383086/how-to-get-visual-studio-2012-to-grey-out-ifdef-instead-of-dimming-it)
[Disable or fix #ifdef-sensitive colouring and intellisense in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586672/disable-or-fix-ifdef-sensitive-colouring-and-intellisense-in-visual-studio)

But these are for older versions of Visual Studio and C++ rather than C# and I couldn't find a similar setting in my Text Editor Options.

[image]

Comment: Is it the color or are you saying you can't use right-click functions inside them?

Comment: both.  Mainly right-click functions and syntax highlighting though, not just changing the specific shade of gray.

Comment: but, why don't you include these compilation symbols in your project properties?

Comment: I'm just using Visual Studio as an editor for Unity - I don't actually run the project from there.  It might work though - how would I do this?

Comment: Use Tools + Options, Environment, Fonts and Colors.

Comment: Are you aware of the [\[`Conditional ("...")`\]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute? That would still format code as normal, but it would only be compiled in certain conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define the `UNITY_ANDROID` symbol (or `UNITY_EDITOR`, ecc..) following these steps (for Visual Studio 2015, but I think it is pretty similar to 2013):

- Open Solution Explorer (from Window menu or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>)
- Right click on your project (should by csharp or csharp.editor if you are using Unity) and click `Properties` from the context menu (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)
- Select the `Build` tab
- Write `UNITY_ANDROID` (or whatever) in `Conditional compilation symbols` field
- Save project or solution

Now your code inside `#if UNITY_ANDROID ... #endif` shouldn't be grayed out anymore (and you should be able to use IntelliSense and all the other stuff).

Comment: I did this excactly but still have the text greyed out

Comment: You should try again (with a new project or on another computer or using different spelling), if it doesn't work (due to some bug) you could report it to microsoft [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt632287.aspx)